# MS Excel - Handling polytherapy medical cases

Tags: database-design, excel

I am working with building a patient database of patients diagnosed with a specific condition. This condition is usually treated with one drug at a time (monotherapy) but at times doctors will opt with a polytherapeutic approach (multiple drugs at the same time). Now, so far with the monotherapy cases I have simply used Excel to enter what drug they were prescribed and what the dosage is.

It gets problematic for me when I need to enter this information for polytherapeutic cases. The variables I use are simply 'Drug', 'Dose', etc. and I would enter the data under the correct variable. I am wondering how I should handle or approach the polytherapeutic cases as these patients will receive two different drugs with two different doses simultaneously.

I hope I have been able to explain this in a simple yet understandable way, but if not, please let me know and I will try to answer any question.

I would appreciate any and all help!

Comment: Interesting problem you are solving but this isn't the best forum on the stackexchange network. It's likely that you'll be better served on StackOverflow (programming centric) or SuperUser. If you were really creating database models, we'd be happy to talk table design and such

Answer (score 0):

Seeing "database design" next to "Excel" makes me cringe.  It can be done, but please consider moving to actual database software soon.

You'll need a table with one record per patient, and another with one record per therapy.  The first table can include lookups to the second to calculate the number of therapies applied, the first date, the last date, whether a therapy is currently active, etc.  Whatever information is relevant summarized per patient.

If the number of different drugs in play is fairly small, you may consider having one column per drug on the patient tab, with the value calculating either a simple "Yes" or "No" value or possibly the number of days of therapy applied for that drug applied (zero if it's not prescribed), or the number of days prescribed, or the number of distinct prescriptions (i.e., the number of records on the second tab for this patient/drug combination).  Of course you can have multiple columns per drug, too: start and end date, maybe.  16,384 columns is the limit, if you don't melt your CPU first.

`COUNTIFS()` and `SUMIFS()` are your friends here.  If you need something especially complex, or you're using an old version of Excel, you'll need array formulae.  Let me know if you need examples.